# How to use a sigmoid function's result as a output of a neuron? What is the meaning of this 0 to 1 value?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I already know that `z = x1 * w1 + x2 * w2 + ... + xi * wi + bias`, and that the sigmoid function is `y = 1 / (1 + e ^ (-z))`; y is 0 to 1.

My question is, how to use the value of y? I have read some articles like:

1. Y is just a number; you have to set up threshold if y > 0.5 to fire,
   so neuron's output will be a binary output.
2. Y is the probability.  If you have multiple classes, then 0 < y < 0.1
   is class A, neuron outputs A; 0.1 <= y < 0.4 is class B, neuron
   outputs B, etc.
3. You can use y's value directly as the output of this neuron.

I am confused as to how I should use the result of the sigmoid function as the output of the neuron.

Comment: can you describe the task you are trying to solve? is it binary classification or multi-class classification or something else?  what machine learning software are you planning to use? all choices you mentioned are valid depending on the task.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the three articles is correct ... for the application under discussion. The very first phrase of answer #1 is quite accurate: "Y is just a number".  Depending on the application, you might use it to classify the input into one of two classes (#1), one of several classes (#2), a probability of having the characteristic the model is investigating, input to the next layer (#3) that has no particular description, or some other interpretation that depends on your application.

A simpler version of your question might be "I just did a linear regression and got the slope of something for my data set.  How do I use this slope?"

The sigmoid function is just one of many useful transformation functions.  It's particular properties include

- Its output is restricted to the range (0, 1).
- It doesn't differentiate much between large values of similar magnitude (i.e. the gradient is close to 0 for large positive and negative inputs).
- It differentiates well between numbers close to 0; the maximum gradient is 1.